# Is it possible to have a key-value pair and map the key to a variable and assign the value to that variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a buffer containing a number of tags and values:

```
=name-tag='John'=address-tag='1st Street'=city-tag='Big City'
```

Scanning this buffer will result in a number of key-value pairs:

```
=name-tag=  John
=addr-tag=  1st Street
=city-tag=  Big City
```

Now I want to map:

- `=name-tag=` to a variable `name`
- `=addr-tag=` to a variable `addr`
- `=city-tag=` to a variable `city`

I found a way to do it but I have a feeling that it is far too complex.
So, if you have any idea to easy map a string to a variable and assign it a value, it would be very helpful.

```
class ValueContainer:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

def set_val(key, value):
    d[key].value = value

name = ValueContainer()
addr = ValueContainer()
city = ValueContainer()

# mapping of the tags to the objects
d = {'name_tag': name, 'addr_tag': addr, 'city_tag': city}

# Parsing a buffer gives me several "tags" and "values"
# Assign the value to the corresponding variable (object)
set_val('name_tag', 'John')
set_val('addr_tag', '1st Street')
set_val('city_tag', 'Big City')

print(name.value)  # John
print(addr.value)  # 1st Street
print(city.value)  # Big City
```

Comment: Why does a normal dictionary not work for you?

Comment: Why not just a simple dictionary `{'name': 'John', 'addr': '1st Street', 'city': 'Big City'}`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a regular expression for this, and I wouldn't set locals, I would just set a dictionary:

```
import re

x = "=name-tag='John'=address-tag='1st Street'=city-tag='Big City'"
pattern = re.compile(r"=([a-z]+)-tag='(.*?)'")
matches = dict(pattern.findall(x))
```

If you want to load those values into an object:

```
class ValueContainer:
    pass

vc = ValueContainer()

for k,v in matches.items():
    setattr(vc, k, v)
```

Comment: Yes setattr is the best approach

Comment: Thanks Greg. To make the question easy to understand, I simplified the tags. In real life they are BER-TLV coded tags, so I cannot use the regular expression (my fault). I will keep you solution in mind because I am sure that somewhere in time it will be very useful.

Answer (score -2):

Using the **setattr** magic method should work for you. If the values map to identical names other than '_tag', I would call name`self.__setattr__(key[0:key.index('_')], value)`

```py
class Container:

    TAGS = {'name_tag': 'name', 'addr_tag': 'addr', 'city_tag': 'city'}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def MapValue(self, key, value):
        self.__setattr__(Container.TAGS[key], value)
```

Comment: Thanks Bugbeeb, I was right, my 'solution' was far too complex. This helps a lot.